# Solving probability

Tags: probability

The question goes ,"In a random survey of $1000$ people, it is found that 7% have lung problem.Of those who have lung problems,40% are heavy smokers,50% are moderate smokers and 10% are non-smokers.For those who do not have any lung problems,10% are heavy smokers,70% are moderate smokers and 20% are non-smokers.If a person is found as a heavy smoker,what is the probability of that person having a lung problem?" I don't know how exactly to tackle this problems,any help will be appreciated

Comment: You should review Bayes theorem.

Comment: @Erick I haven't been exposed to the theorem

Comment: Conditional probability $Pr(A\mid B) = \frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$.  Rearranging we have $Pr(B)Pr(A\mid B) = Pr(A\cap B)$.  By symmetry we have $Pr(B)Pr(A\mid B)=Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)Pr(B\mid A)$.  By dividing we have $Pr(A\mid B) = \frac{Pr(A)Pr(B\mid A)}{Pr(B)}$.  This final result is what is often referred to as Baye's theorem (though it is just a special case for two sets.  The full theorem goes deeper).

Comment: Here, the question asks you to find $Pr(\text{lung problem}\mid \text{heavy smoker})$.  Applying the theorem and you'll reach a result, noting that to apply the theorem, you must also find $Pr(\text{heavy smoker})$ which should be clear from a tree diagram.

Comment: @JMoravitz it is clear to me now.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** We want to compute $\Pr[\text{lung prob} \mid \text{heavy}]$, which is given by:
$$
\frac{\Pr[\text{lung prob}]\Pr[\text{heavy} \mid \text{lung prob}]}{\Pr[\text{lung prob}]\Pr[\text{heavy} \mid \text{lung prob}] + \Pr[\text{no lung prob}]\Pr[\text{heavy} \mid \text{no lung prob}]}
$$